# Laptop not charging after switching from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, battery

i just recently upgraded from Windows 10 to Ubuntu to try it out. the issue is that my battery just does not charge at all. it's like it's not even plugged in! not even when it's on. I didn't have this issue with Windows. when I leave my laptop plugged in it just dies like it's not plugged in. I've checked the status of the battery and the AC adapter, and it says the AC is offline and the battery is discharging. I have an HP ProBook 6460b. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1: make sure you update after change to ubuntu,for the system to update the latest driver for the system by command: sudo apt-get update

2: Make sure you plug in the correct direction of the adapter and plug it carefully, you can try to unplug and plug in it securely on your own computer or another computer

for me result after you try all of above step :))